# Appending UIButton with NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uibutton, nsarray

I have this code to show some text in a textview from SQLite DB..

```
NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
    [combined appendFormat:@" %d   %@", idx, [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];
}

self.multiPageView.text = combined;
self.multiPageView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:self.fontSize];
```

`delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish` is the `NSArray`
`multiPageView` is the `UITextView`

i put the above loop function to get the Numbers according to the text,for example `1 hello 2 iPhone 3 iPad 4 mac etc etc..`i just want **UIButton** between the text instead of `1 2 3 4 ..`for example i want  `unbutton hello unbutton iPhone etc etc`.because i need to make some touch events  from it.how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't place buttons inline in a text view. If that's a requirement for you, consider using a `UIWebView`.

Comment: you cannot store UIButton instances in a NSString, you need to add the Buttons as subviews to the scrollview

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve?  The text view lets users edit the text, is that what you want?  The other commenters think that you want to add buttons as subviews of the text, do you?  Please try to describe the objective functionally, from the user perspective.

Comment: @Jenox actually its not a textview ,,its a UIview..i am drawing the text in the above view,for make it easy i said it is a textview...is that possible now?

Comment: Anyway,you should put the buttons above that view and put spaces beneath them,as i wrote in my answer

Comment: @NikitaPestrov but the text is dynamic...it my be 10,some times it may be 100..so i got the correct code to appent the number with the string but need button instead of numbers.is that possible to make array of button and append it to the text?

Comment: No.But you can dynamicly add those buttons,why not?

Comment: @NikitaPestrov very sorry Nikita ,,i didn't understand it.can you please elabrote little more,how to active this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place UIButtons between some text in textview, there is no other way but to place it as a separate view just above. So you'll need to add spaces beneath those buttons, the amount of those you should calculate yourself, based on the size of your buttons.
So, if you would like yo see something like this:

```
Press here [UIButton] or here [Another UIButton],
```

your text string should look like this

```
Press here            or here                   ,
```

So when you add the buttons on those places, it would look just like you wish.

## UPDATE

Seems like we need some more code here, so here it is:
First, you'll need to calculate the size of a letter. Let's assume that it is 10 pixels height and 8 pixels.No, let's just call that **letterHeight** and **letterWidth**.Let's also  assume that you want 64x10 pixels buttons. So, we will need 64/8=8 +2 spaces to out behind that button(2 to make borders around that)
So, here we go

```
NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];
int letterHeight = 10;
int letterWidth = 8;
   for(NSString *verse in delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish) {
       [combined appendFormat:@"          %@",verse];//10 spaces there
//You have to experiment with this, but idea is that your x coordinate is just proportional to the length of the line you are inserting your button in, and y is proportional to number of lines
    int xCoordinate = [combined length]*letterWidth%(int)(self.multiPageView.frame.size.width);
    int yCoordinate = [combined length]*letterWidth/(int)(self.multiPageView.frame.size.width)*letterHeight;
    
     UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,64,10)];
     [self.multiPageView addSubview:newButton];
}
 self.multiPageView.text = combined;
```

Comment: You loop the same way, every time adding UIButton to that view,not to hard,really

Comment: i can show you a code that built a coloumview with buttons dynamically.

Comment: I'll write code for that in five minutes,just get to my mac first

Comment: No,you should read it, and then play with letterWidth and letterHeight to find the right values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10369/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-nikita-pestrov)

Comment: haii Nikita ,,i get only one button at the top of the view..iput tho statically   int xCoordinate = [combined length]*letterWidth%(764)*letterWidth;...